# Scale numeric vector to specified mean, min, and max

Tags: r, scale, rescale

This should be an easy question... I'm looking to scale a numeric vector to a specified mean **and range**.

For instance, I would like to scale a vector, `x`, to mean = 1, min = 0, and max = 2. Here's my vector `x`, with min = 0, max = 1:

```
> x <- runif(100, 0, 1)
> mean(x)
[1] 0.4897899
```

My first thought was to scale to a mean = 0, using `scale()`, and add 1... But this doesn't address the issue of the range:

```
> mean(scale(x)+1)
[1] 1
```

But, this results in negative values:

```
> sum((scale(x)+1) < 0)
[1] 21
```

My next thought was to use `scales::rescale()`, but it appears to only have arguments for setting the desired range.

This seems like an easy question, but I'm stumped! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

-Alex.

Comment: Not easy: actually impossible in general. If you don't want to distort the scale of the values (i.e. if you are limiting to yourself to **affine transformations** where you're allowed to add/subtract a constant and/or multiply/divide by a scaling constant), you can't in general satisfy three criteria simultaneously (min, max, *and* mean)

Comment: Thank you, Dr. Bolker. Now that you mention it, it seems so obvious! Perhaps I was asking the wrong question. By some strange coincidence, I'm actually trying to follow your previous advice about using frequency weights in glmm models. You mentioned scaling the weights to mean = 1. I assumed weights must be non-zero, so I've been trying to scale my weights vector to a mean = 1 and *at least* a min = 0. Maybe I should repost this question, but could you advise how best to scale frequency weights?

Comment: Assuming you have a vector of weights `w` that are **all non-negative** to begin with `all(w>=0)`, then `w2 <- w/mean(w)` should do the trick. (Proof: `mean(w2) == mean(w/mean(w)) == mean(w)/mean(w) == 1`).  Assuming your weights aren't all zero to begin with (which would be weird), the mean will be positive, so the rescaled weights will be non-negative and have mean 1, which is all you need.

Comment: So simple. Thank you. As always, you're help is much appreciated.

Comment: it's mildly cheesy, but you could rewrite this question to focus on your original question ("I have arbitrary weights, I want to convert them to frequency weights") and then answer your own question ...